# Dataset publish date

Tags: powershell, powerbi

Is there a way to determine when a dataset was last published?  I see in the UI when the dataset was last refreshed, and I can inspect the recent refresh history.  Also, through PowerShell, I can use `Get-PowerBIDataset` to see when the dataset was created.  I'm not seeing any way to determine when a dataset was last published, that is, changed.